# How to load the array of icons dynamically in toolbar in android?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am working in library format and I have design different headers. 
But the library should have some interfaces. So from main activity in the project, you call the library and send the array of icons that will be loaded dynamically in the toolbar of the header.

MainActivity.java code is:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) 
findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();

NavigationView navigationView = 
(NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

There is an option to load the array dynamically in the toolbar

[image]

Comment: I am not getting you question are you want to show toolbar icon or something else.

Comment: Mouzam! Please delete this post, this image has copyrights and its not yours. Sould not be here

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try this one will help you:

You just crate menu item in your Activity then you can implement multiple icons.

1. Create a menu folder in your existing resource res folder.
2. Create a main.xml file in menu folder.

   main.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_item_one"
       android:title="Camera"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
       app:showAsAction="always" />

   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_item_two"
       android:title="Send"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
       app:showAsAction="always" />
   </menu>
   ```
3. In your activity, override onCreateOptionsMenu() and onOptionsItemSelected() to work with option menus.

   ActionBarActivity.java

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
       // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
       // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
       int id = item.getItemId();

       //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
       if (id == R.id.action_camera) {

           // Do something
           return true;
       }
       if (id == R.id.action_send) {

           // Do something
           return true;
       }

       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
   ```

Comment: ok thanks, but i have to load array of icons dynamically with an option available on the interface...

Comment: Which interface just mention your class where you are using that interface.

Comment: i have different headers for tabbed activity. and working in library format.
Then inside i make a library where will be the design and an the logic of the header.

the library should have some interfaces. so from main activity in project i call the library and send the array of icons that will be loaded in the toolbar of the header.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the icon of the items of your menu by calling the method setIcon(int) of the desired item. In this example there is only one item that changes its icon if the user liked or not a movie. "liked" is a boolean that is changed in other part of the code and then invalidateOptionsMenu() is called to recreate the menu (onCreateOptionsMenu is called after invalidation).

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.your_xml_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.getItem(0);
    if (liked) {
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.liked);
    } else {
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.not_liked);
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

You can also change the visibility of an item calling item.setVisible(false); or even inflate different xml for different configurations.